# Clamp values in gnuplot splot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnu, surface

I'm using `splot` to visualize the fitness histogram for an optimization problem. In this scenario positive Z values (say in the +2 - +15 range) representing good solutions are of particular interest whereas negative values don't provide much insight, i.e. it doesn't matter if a bad solution as a Z value of -50, -500 or -5000.

Using the `autorange` option all the interesting bits around +/- 0 are 'scaled away' (i.e. mostly flat to include neg. peaks in the surface) so I'm now using an explicit `zrange` of `[-bestValue:bestValue]` to focus the plot on the interesting Z values.

Now the development of best solutions close to `0` can be traced much better, however the surface is rendered with 'holes' for neg. Z values exceeding the range:
[image: Surface with limited Z range rendered with 'holes']

This is very confusing to look at/interpret.
(FWIW the `hidden3d` option is enabled)

Can we (`gnuplot`) 'fill' the holes in some way, e.g. by clamping neg. values in the surface plot instead of just dropping the points from the surface?

Comment: You can probably use the ternary operator to do the clamping: something like `splot "filename" using 1:2:($3 > -50 ? $3 : -50)` might work

Comment: @user8153 works like a breeze!